# overload shift so it supports chaining and also should work with cout

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cout

So I tried to make program according to Title of this question, and my code only couts the first one.

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Distance {
    int feet;
    int inches;
    string display();

 public:
    Distance();
    Distance(int, int);
    Distance operator+(Distance);
    friend string operator<<(ostream&, Distance);
    friend string operator<<(string, Distance);
    friend string operator<<(Distance, Distance);
};

Distance::Distance() {
    feet = 0;
    inches = 0;
}

Distance::Distance(int feet, int inches) {
    this->feet = feet;
    this->inches = inches;
}

string Distance::display() {
    stringstream str;
    str << feet << '\'' << inches << '\n';
    return str.str();
}

string operator<<(ostream& os, Distance distance) {
    string out = distance.display();
    os << out;
    return out;
}

string operator<<(string str, Distance distance) {
    return (str + distance.display());
}

string operator<<(Distance distance1, Distance distance2) {
    return distance1.display() + distance2.display();
}

int main() {
    Distance distance(5, 8);
    Distance distance2(5, 9);

    cout << distance << distance2;
}
```

I've tried multiple ways and one that worked is if I put brackets in that cout line like this `cout << (distance << distance2);` then it works fine!

But I want it to work without brackets like you know how we do it with strings `cout << "abc" << "def";` Now I don't know if it's even possible with objects.

Here are some screenshots of output

without brackets ↴ `cout << distance << distance2;`

[image: without brackets]

with brackets ↴ `cout << (distance << distance2);`

[image: with brackets]

If it's not possible to get same output as with brackets without using brackets then can someone please let me know how it works with strings ? like we don't put brackets with strings yet still it displays whole.

`cout << "abc" << "def";`

output: "abcdef"

Comment: If you want to be able to "chain" usage of `operator<<()`, the left operand needs to be a reference, and the function needs to return that reference.   So, for example, the version that works with `std::ostream` would be something like `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &s, Distance d) { output_d_to_s();   return s;}`

Comment: `operator<<(ostream&, ...)` should be returning a `std::ostream&` reference to allow for chaining with other stream operator calls.

Comment: You might benefit from taking the time to write out in words what the problem is, rather than trying to express yourself in code. Be detailed and clear. Good code starts from good specifications, and forcing yourself to write out the specifications often reveals (and fills!) gaps in your understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal thing to do is to simply have one overload

```
//This requires a friend declaration inside the class first.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Distance &distance) {
    return os << distance.feet << '\'' << distance.inches << '\n';
}
```

This lets you chain as expected:

```
std::cout << 3 << myDistance << myDistance << "hi!"
```

Answer (score 3):

To support chaining, `operator<<(ostream&, Distance)` needs to return the `ostream&` it is given, not `string`. Also, the `Distance` should be passed by const reference:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Distance &distance) {
    os << distance.display();
    return os;
}
```

`operator<<(string, Distance)` and `operator<<(Distance, Distance)` simply make no sense to have, and so they should be removed completely.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented `operator<<(ostream&, Distance)` incorrectly.

Since you have it returning a `string`, the line:

```
cout << distance << distance2;
```

Evaluates `cout << distance` first, and then resolves to...

```
{temporary std::string} << distance2;
```

... which of course doesn't print anything more.

Have the function return a reference to the **left** parameter instead.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Distance distance) {
    string out = distance.display();
    os << out;
    return os;
}
```